# SQL Server SUM() 2 decimal

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2005

I have record like this

```
column_name
1.23424
4.32524
5.24123
7.84927
10.76192
2.77263
```

how to to SUM() just only 2 decimal?

```
column_name
1.23
4.33
5.24
7.85
10.76
2.77
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You mean [ROUND()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)?

But even that is tricky. Read the docs, and you'll see it still returns a plain numeric expression, which likely still includes trailing zeros.  You may need to do extra string processing to get the exact display value you want, and that's likely better done on the client.